# borrar archivos mas antiguos que la semana actual mediante archivo .bat

Tags: windows, batch

¿como puedo, en un archivo .bat, borrar los archivos de un determinado directorio, que tengan extension .sql y que hayan sido creados antes de la semana actual?He encontrado esto pero no me atrevo a probarlo no sea que me haga un estropicio:

```
forfiles -p -s -m *.* -d -25 -c «cmd /c del @path»
```

Comment: Si tienes miedo de correr algo que no es tan evidente lo que hace, tal vez consideraría usar otro lenguaje de scripting que si entiendas o que sea mas fácil de entender como Python.